# Solving 3x3 Rubik's cube with commutator

Tags: rubiks-cube

Is it possible to solve the 3x3 Rubik's with only the Y commutator. i.e. [F,R'] = FR'F'R

Comment: Hi, David! Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Could you provide more details on your question, such as what you mean by Y commutator, and the significance of the notation at the end of the question?

Comment: The notation at the end is pretty standard for solving Rubik's cube.  F means rotation the front face clockwise, F' counter clockwise.  R is the right face. A commutator is a math term in group theory that you see in Rubik's cube books.

Comment: I think the information you mentioned would be good to add to the question, in addition to perhaps the definition of the commutator term.

Answer (score 1):

A commutator always produces an even permutation.  If you use only commutators you cannot change the parity of the position, i.e. the parity of the permutation that took you from a solved cube to the current position.

But all it takes is a single 1/4 turn to change the parity.

Obviously if you apply only this commutator on the same 2 faces, F and R, you won't solve the cube.

But by combining variations of this commutator, you can do simple permutations:
([R,U])3 exchanges 2 time 2 corners.
([R,U])3 ([F'U'])3  rotates 3 corners.

By carefully composing simple permutations you can end up with all the basic permutations, exchanging 3 corners, or 3 edges, or flipping edges or rotating corners.  With these you can complete the cube.

Only the parity prevents, strictly speaking, to solve half of the positions.